# How to save multiple baked textures?

Tags: python, texture-baking, file-browser

I am making different sets of baked textures for multiple objects and it takes a very long time to save them one by one for each set. Is there a way to save all baked textures in batch process?

Comment: There are various addons that allow batch baking, both [paid](https://cgcookiemarkets.com/blender/all-products/baketool/) and [free](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?345126-Meltdown-bake-tools).

Answer (score 1):

Switch to Texture Paint mode and use the Save All Images button.  It will save any images that have been altered so long as they have already been previously saved.

[image]

Normally, I make sure everything is savable by preparing the textures in the folder on the hard-drive and then drag and drop them into the materials. This is quick and Blender will have a location to save them to when you use the image save button.